# pattern that works on regex101 but doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to set a pattern for a field in my form. the pattern must have the following characteristics:

1.it must be between 8 to 12 characters.

2.it can contain numbers,letters(uppercase or lowercase),"dot","dash" and "underline"

3.it must start with letters.

I managed to find a pattern that works on https://regex101.com/ but when I write the JavaScript the code doesn't work.

here is the pattern:  ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{7,11}$

and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

username: <input type="text" name="uname" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}$" id="uname" required="required"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is that doesn't work. What inputs have you tried that you think should work but do not work?

Comment: for example "s_123asd" is okay in regex

but it is a mismatch in my code

Answer (score 2):

In the regex, remove the `^` and `$` they are not necessary. The Demo below works as expected and it uses a live test server (although not really necessary since your main concern is the request attribute works properly). To test and confirm, after a successful submit, look for the server response in the iframe located below the form.

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form name="regForm" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target='response'>

    username: <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}" required="required"><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"><br><br>
    <h4>iFrame will display test server response</h4>
    <iframe src='about:blank' name='response'></iframe>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```